# boot-starter library that adds extra endpoints (just like actuator)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I'd like to create a boot-starter project that adds extra endpoints to any boot app that the starter is added. Similar to the boot-actuator starter.
I've created a new spring-boot project with boot-actuator starter. Created `HelloEndpoint` that extended Actuator's `Endpoint` class. Verified that it adds `/hello` endpoint to my boot app.

Now I'd like to create a starter library from this boot project. Thus any boot project to which I added my lib (starter) would have `/hello` endpoint. I looked at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-customizing-endpoints-programmatically and created the configuration class and `HelloMvcEndpoint` that delegates to `HelloEndpoint`. Also created `spring.factories` file with hopefully correct content.

When I build my project and add it as a dependency to a boot project with web-starter i see that the boot app doesn't get the `/hello` endpoint :-(

My project is shared via Github: https://github.com/BoykoAlex/endpoint-trial

First of all, am I on the right track to achieve what I want? And if yes, can you please tell me what I'm missing? Is there an existing example of what I'm trying to accomplish already available you can point me to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer here:
https://github.com/yingzhuo/spring-auto/tree/master/spring-auto-endpoint
An example of something i wanted ti implement.